# How to Endpoint.broadcast to the topic and event of another channel?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two channels defined.
First One is

```
defmodule AppServerWeb.FirstChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join("first:*", auth_key, socket) do
      send(self, {:after_join, 12})
      {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_info({:after_join, count}, socket) do
        App.Endpoint.broadcast "second:*", "activeusers", %{users: count}
        {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_out(event, payload, socket) do
      push socket, event, payload
      {:noreply, socket}
  end

end
```

And second one is

```
defmodule AppServerWeb.SecondChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join("second:*", auth_key, socket) do
      {:ok, socket}
  end


  def handle_out(event, payload, socket) do
      push socket, event, payload
      {:noreply, socket}
  end

end
```

And in my client side I have

```
socket = new Phoenix.Socket("/socket", {params: {userToken: "123"}})
socket.connect();
channel1 = socket.channel("first:*", {auth: "foo"})
channel2 = socket.channel("second:*", {auth: "foo"})
channel1.join()   //successful join
channel2.join()   //successful join
channel2.on("activeusers", function (msg) {
        console.log(msg)   //This one never triggers
});
```

So basically all i need is to broadcast on a topic from channel one and listen to it from a client joined to channel2, this is as far as i can go reading docs, which is not working.. where did i screw up?

Comment: What error you get? What problem do you experience in general? `App.Endpoint.broadcast "second:*", "activeusers" %{users: count}` is not a valid Elixir syntax. Please describe the issue, the statement “I dunno understand anything” is not a valid question for SO.

Comment: My question is in the title. Yes i forgot to add a comma in Endpoint statement, which is now fixed and that was a copy paste error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [`Phoenix.Channel`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#module-broadcasting-to-an-external-topic):

> In some cases, you will want to broadcast messages without the context of a socket. This could be for broadcasting from within your channel to an external topic, or broadcasting from elsewhere in your application like a controller or another process. Such can be done via your endpoint:
>
> ```
> # within channel
> def handle_in("new_msg", %{"uid" => uid, "body" => body}, socket) do
>   ...
>   broadcast_from! socket, "new_msg", %{uid: uid, body: body}
>   MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast_from! self(), "room:superadmin",
>     "new_msg", %{uid: uid, body: body}
>   {:noreply, socket}
> end
> ```

That said, you should use `broadcast_from!/4` passing `self()` as the first parameter.

Comment: My question is how to boradcast it to another channel... And using the other channels handle_out to pass it to client